# Deque with circular array implementation

Tags: java, deque, arraydeque

This is programming exercise from Lafore's Data Structures & Algorithms book:

[image]

So far I have this:

```
public class DequeLong {
private int maxSize;
private long[] dequeArray;
private int front;
private int rear;
private int nItems;

public DequeLong(int size){
    maxSize = size;
    dequeArray = new long[maxSize];
    front = 0;
    rear = -1;
    nItems = 0;
}

public void insertLeft(long j){
    if(rear == maxSize - 1)
        rear = -1;
    dequeArray[++rear] = j;
    nItems++;
    getDequeArray();
}

public void insertRight(long j){
    if(front == maxSize)
        front = 0;
    dequeArray[front] = j;
    front++;
    nItems++;
    getDequeArray();
}

public long removeLeft(){
    long temp = dequeArray[rear];
    if(rear == 0)
        rear = maxSize - 1;
    else{
        rear--;
    }
    nItems--;
    getDequeArray();
    return temp;
}

public long removeRight(){
    long temp = dequeArray[front++];
    if(front == maxSize)
        front = 0;
    nItems--;
    getDequeArray();
    return temp;
}

public long peekFront(){
    return dequeArray[front];
}

public long peekRear(){
    return  dequeArray[rear];
}

public boolean isFull(){
    return nItems == maxSize;
}

public boolean isEmpty(){
    return nItems == 0;
}

public int size(){
    return nItems;
}

public long get(int i){
    return dequeArray[i];
}

public void getDequeArray(){
    System.out.print("[");
    for(int i = 0; i < nItems; i++){
        System.out.print(dequeArray[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.print("]");
    System.out.println();
}
```

}

And main class:

```
public class DequeApp {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    DequeLong dl = new DequeLong(5);

    //check stack - insertLeft() & removeLeft()
    dl.insertLeft(100);
    dl.insertLeft(200);
    dl.insertLeft(300);
    dl.insertLeft(400);
    dl.insertLeft(500);
    dl.removeLeft();
    dl.removeLeft();
    dl.insertLeft(600);
    dl.insertLeft(700);
    System.out.println("");
    for(int i = 0; i < dl.size(); i++){
        System.out.print(dl.get(i) + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("");

    while(!dl.isEmpty())
        System.out.println("removed: " + dl.removeLeft());
    System.out.println("*************************");

    //check queue - insertLeft() & removeRight()
    dl.insertLeft(1_000);
    dl.insertLeft(2_000);
    dl.insertLeft(3_000);
    dl.insertLeft(4_000);
    dl.insertLeft(5_000);
    dl.removeRight();
    dl.removeRight();
    dl.insertLeft(6_000);
    dl.insertLeft(7_000);
    System.out.println("");
    for(int i = 0; i < dl.size(); i++){
        System.out.print(dl.get(i) + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("");

    while(!dl.isEmpty())
        System.out.println("removed: " + dl.removeRight());
    System.out.println("*************************");

    //insertRight() & removeLeft()
    dl.insertRight(10_000);
    dl.insertRight(20_000);
    dl.insertRight(30_000);
    dl.insertRight(40_000);
    dl.insertRight(50_000);

    dl.removeLeft();
    dl.removeLeft();
    dl.insertRight(60_000);
    dl.insertRight(70_000);
    System.out.println("");
    for(int i = 0; i < dl.size(); i++){
        System.out.print(dl.get(i) + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("");

    while(!dl.isEmpty())
        System.out.println("removed: " + dl.removeLeft());
    System.out.println("*************************");

    //insertRight() & removeRight()
    dl.insertRight(100_000);
    dl.insertRight(200_000);
    dl.insertRight(300_000);
    dl.insertRight(400_000);
    dl.insertRight(500_000);
    dl.removeRight();
    dl.removeRight();
    dl.insertRight(600_000);
    dl.insertRight(700_000);
    System.out.println("");
    for(int i = 0; i < dl.size(); i++){
        System.out.print(dl.get(i) + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("");

    while(!dl.isEmpty())
        System.out.println("removed: " + dl.removeRight());
    System.out.println("*************************");
}
```

}

Questions:

1) Right now I am applying all operations on the same object, am I doing it right? or I have to create new object(or add reset method to existing one) in order to apply insertLeft(), insertRight(), removeLeft(), removeRight() combos sequentially?

2) If it's possible to use methods sequentially, does my code returns correct results?

Comment: If you were to create a new deque (or reset one after every operation), your deque would only ever hold a single element, making it pretty useless. As for the results, well, are they correct? Presumably you understand how deques work, so you should be able to test whether it works or not?

Comment: @Kayaman thanks, it doesn't throw exception but I can't say it's correct because of that. First of all, insertLeft() + removeLeft() gives stack and I can see it works. insertLeft() + removeRight() should give queue  but I get unexpected result(in my opinion) because i remove two items and add again another two(second example), not sure if it's the way it should work.

Comment: You're right in that a lack of exceptions doesn't mean code is correct. But I don't know what those unexpected results are, and I don't tend to run people's code here, so you'll have to either explain yourself clearer (by editing the post) or hope that someone runs your code and debugs it for you.